# jhipster eureka registry with nonstandard server.servlet-path

Tags: java, jhipster, jhipster-registry

### My Problem

I am setting up a jhipster based microservice infrastructure behind an nginx which serves as a reverse proxy.

Where other components like grafana or kibana allow to configure a `server_root_url` or a `server_basepath` - to access them under `example.com/grafana` or `example.com/kibana`. I am struggeling to do the same thing with the eureka-cloud-config-registry part.

If I forward to the registry via nginx every request on `/registry`, unfortunately there are links in the registry like `/api/routes` - which in my case would go to the gateway which "runs" under `/` and therefore fail to work.

### What I found out up to this point

I know that this component is based on Spring Boot 1.5.9 - which has a config option `server.context-path` which I can set (see `(1)` below) to `/registry` unfortunately when I want to access `localhost:8761/registry` I get an HTTP 401 Unauthorized error, which I tried to fix by adding `security.ignored` (see `(2)` below), without any luck.

### My config

This is what my `jhipster-registry.yml` looks like:

```
version: '2'
services:
    jhipster-registry:
        image: jhipster/jhipster-registry:v3.2.4
        volumes:
            - ./central-server-config:/central-config
        # By default the JHipster Registry runs with the "dev" and "native"
        # Spring profiles.
        # "native" profile means the filesystem is used to store data, see
        # http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html
        environment:
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev,native
            - SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD=admin
            - JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=admin
            - JHIPSTER_LOGGING_LOGSTASH_ENABLED=false
            - JHIPSTER_METRICS_LOGS_ENABLED=false
            - SERVER_SERVLET_PATH=/registry      # (1)
            - SECURITY_IGNORED=/**,/registry     # (2)
        ports: #docker-host:docker-container
            - 8761:8761
```

I run this using `docker-compose -f jhipster-registry.yml up jhipster-registry`